# Ubuntu невероятно долго загружается

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kde

У меня довольно мощный пк - `ryzen 3 2200g, gtx 1660, 8gb ddr4, ssd под ubuntu`
Стоит ubuntu 20.04 рядом с windows 10
Винда загружается примерно за 20-30 сек, а вот линукс...

Когда пк работает на винде, а потом перезагружается на линукс, то загрузка примерно 20 секунд.
Если пк работает линуксе, потом выключается и включается опять линукс, то загрузка минуты 3-4!
Но недавно я установил себе `kde-desktopt`, но он мне не понравился, я его удалил.
После этого загрузка стала почти 6 минут!!!!

```
~$ systemd - analyze
Startup finished in 6.989 s(firmware) + 14.739 s(loader) + 4 min 30.082 s(kernel) + 51.189 s(userspace) = 5 min 43.001 s
graphical.target reached after 36.150 s in userspace
```

```js
~$ systemd-analyze blame
34.439s udisks2.service                        
29.535s upower.service                         
20.980s plymouth-quit-wait.service             
 5.691s fwupd.service                          
 2.149s dev-sda2.device                        
 1.481s mysql.service                          
 1.326s snapd.service                          
  919ms man-db.service                         
  892ms logrotate.service                      
  774ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount
  773ms snap-phpstorm-212.mount                
  763ms networkd-dispatcher.service            
  747ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount
  737ms dev-loop1.device                       
  729ms dev-loop4.device                       
  725ms dev-loop3.device                       
  723ms dev-loop9.device                       
  712ms dev-loop2.device                       
  698ms dev-loop5.device                       
  676ms dev-loop0.device                       
  667ms dev-loop8.device                       
  662ms snap-orchis\x2dthemes-1.mount          
  661ms dev-loop6.device
```

В чём проблема и как это решить??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: говорят, что такие проблемы могут вызывать некоторые usb устройства, попробуйте отключить флешки и внешние диски снова попробовать

Comment: приведите вывод команды  `dmesg -T` после долгой загрузки системы